# Having trouble scraping info from zillow page, not sure what the problem is

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm very new to web scraping and just coding in general. I'm trying to scrape info about listings from Zillow. I was able to gather things like listing address, price, and links fairly easily. However, now I'm trying to find the HOA fee from the listing but when I try to scrape it, it works for some listings but not others. I tried running the code over and over again to see if the problem was isolated to specific links but it has proven to be random each time.

I've tried searching the pages for other CSS classes and double checking my code (I probably missed something wrong) and I couldn't find a solution.

Here is my code, sorry if its super messy and unoptimized. Also I used "Invalid HOA fee" as a placeholder for the listings that it failed to scrape. Also the program takes a minute or so to run.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import random

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.zillow.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' + str(random.randint(1, 1000)), #randomint bypasses captcha
}


with requests.session() as i:

    city = str(input("City To Search In: ")) + "/"

    page = 1
    end_page = 10
    url = ""
    urlList = []
    request = ""
    requestList = []

    while page <= end_page:
        url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/" + city + "/" + str(page) + "_p"
        urlList.append(url)
        page += 1

    for url in urlList:
        request = i.get(url, headers=headers)
        requestList.append(request)

rawInfo = ""
rawInfoList = []

for request in requestList:
    rawInfo = soup(request.content, "html.parser")
    rawInfoList.append(rawInfo)

addressList = [] 
priceList = [] 
linkList = [] 
requestList2 = [] 
listingInfoList = [] 
hoaList = []
finalHoaList = []
newHoa = []

for rawInfo in rawInfoList:
    for address in rawInfo.find_all("address"):
        addressList.append(address.text)
    for price in rawInfo.find_all(class_="StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-85-1__sc-yipmu-0 bqsBln"): 
        priceList.append(price.text)
    for link in rawInfo.find_all(class_="StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-85-1__sc-yipmu-0 gdfTyO property-card-link", href = True): 
        linkList.append(link["href"]) 


for link in linkList:
    request2 = requests.session().get(link, headers=headers)
    requestList2.append(request2)

for request2 in requestList2:
    listingInfo = soup(request2.content, "html.parser")
    listingInfoList.append(listingInfo)

count = 0

for listingInfo in listingInfoList:
    hoaList.append([])
    for hoa in listingInfo.find_all(class_="Text-c11n-8-84-0__sc-aiai24-0 dpf__sc-2arhs5-3 qxgaF kOlNqB"):
        hoaList[count].append(hoa.text)
    if len(hoaList[count]) == 0:
        hoaList[count].append("Invalid HOA fee")
    count += 1

for i in range(len(hoaList)):
    finalHoa = list(filter(lambda hoa: hoa.endswith("HOA fee"), hoaList[i])) 
    finalHoaList.append(finalHoa)
    if len(finalHoaList[i]) == 0:
        finalHoaList[i].append("$0 annually HOA fee")

print(finalHoaList)
print(linkList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The class names that you're using appear to be different on each page:

```
"Text-c11n-8-84-0__sc-aiai24-0 dpf__sc-2arhs5-3 qxgaF kOlNqB"
```

Only the first part of that "Text-c11n-8-84-0__sc-aiai24-0" seems to be fixed, the other parts vary from page to page.

I think you could replace the two FOR loops at the bottom by this:

```
for listingInfo in listingInfoList:
    element_list = listingInfo.find_all(class_="Text-c11n-8-84-0__sc-aiai24-0")
    hoa = [element for element in element_list if element.text.endswith("HOA fee")]
    if hoa:
        finalHoaList.append(hoa[0].text.strip())
    else:
        finalHoaList.append("$0 annually HOA fee")
```

Here we first find all the elements with class "Text-c11n-8-84-0__sc-aiai24-0" and then find which one ends with "HOA Fee"

"if hoa" is shorthand for saying "if hoa != []" or "if len(hoa) > 0".  If the list is not empty then "if hoa" will return True